# Hangfire .net framework, schedule on a specific queue

Tags: c#, hangfire

I have an issue when scheduling a job using hangfire.
Since I have multiple server instance for different apps, when I schedule a job I need to choose on which server or queue otherwise the job may fail if the target function is not found.

I tried to post the same question on hangfire forum but till now nobody answered.
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/schedule-on-a-specific-server/9263

Is there any solution for this?

I tried the solution proposed in the below link, didn't work for me.
https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/schedule-on-a-specific-server/9263

Comment: Are you allowed to use something other than hangfire? From my experience its easier to just create queues in Kafka and process them however you want. For scheduling you can use Quartz.Net. Hangfire seems simple at first but absolute nightmare later in support.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.